# How can I change the fontweight of an item at click method - React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a react code below where I iterate over in an array of grocery list. I created a state change and a style variable that will change only one item at a time when clicked.

However it did not work. For some reason when I click on one item it turns all of them bold.

```
const App = () => (
    <div><GroceryListItem /></div>
);

class GroceryListItem extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div><GroceryList groceryItems={['Cucumber', 'Kale']}/></div>
    );
  }
}

class GroceryList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      done: false
    };
  }

  onClickItem(){
    this.setState({
        done: !this.state.done
      });
  }

 render(){

  var style = {
      fontWeight: this.state.done ? 'bold' : 'normal'
    };

   return (
    <ul>
      {
        this.props.groceryItems.map(item => <li style={style} onClick={this.onClickItem.bind(this)} key={item}>{item}</li>)
      }
    </ul>

   );
  }
}
```

Any idea why is this not working and how to fix it? 
PS. Suggestions on how to improve my code is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the state onClick, and changing the style variable which is accessible to the complete render function. You just need to know which of the element is clicked and store it in your state. You can try the below method.

```
class GroceryList extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    selected: null
  };
}

onClickItem (item) {
  this.setState({
    selected: item
  })
}

render(){
return (
       <ul>
       {
        this.props.groceryItems.map(item => <li style={{'fontWeight': this.state.selected === item ? 'bold' : 'normal'}} onClick={this.onClickItem.bind(this, item)} key={item}>{item}</li>)
       }
    </ul>
)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the css variable in state and change on onClick

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => (
<div><GroceryListItem /></div>
);

class GroceryListItem extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
 super(props);
}

render(){
return (
   <div><GroceryList groceryItems={['Cucumber', 'Kale']}/></div>
  );
 }
}

class GroceryList extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
  done: false,
  style: "normal"
 };
}

onClickItem(item){
let style = {
    [item]: "bold"
}
this.setState({
    done: !this.state.done,
    style: style
  },() => {});
 }

render(){
return (
<ul>
  {
    this.props.groceryItems.map(item => {

        {console.log(this.state.style[item],"this.state")}
        return (<li style={{fontWeight: this.state.style[item] || "normal"}} id={item} onClick={this.onClickItem.bind(this,item)} key={item}>{item}</li>
        )
    })
}
</ul>

 );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```