# ReactStrap Collapse prevent toggle of siblings onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I researched this answer in couple of stackoverflow threads but nothing worked so far. I am using Reactstrap Collapse toggle, but instead of an outside button, I have the onClick method on an "li" tag.

The problem is that I am trying to stopPropagation to the additional "li's" without success. so if I click on one li, every li open, and closes.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Col, Collapse, ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from 'reactstrap';
import Data from '../data/data.json';

class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = { 
      collapse: false, 
      Data: Data
    };
  }

  toggle = (e) => {
    this.setState({ collapse: !this.state.collapse });
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Col xs={12} md={6} lg={6} className="right-col">
      
        <ListGroup onClick={this.toggle}>
          {  Data.projectLinks.map((link) => {
          return  <ListGroupItem key={link.title} onClick={(e) => {this.toggle(e)}}>
            {link.title}
            <Collapse isOpen={this.state.collapse}>
              <p>{link.description}</p>
            </Collapse>
          </ListGroupItem> 
          })
        }
        </ListGroup>
      </Col>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

If you have any idea how to accomplish this, or another solution here, I appreciate it.

Comment: You are changing the state of the whole component. I have answered this question here
https://stackoverflow.com/q/48615887/8890083

Your question is of similar kind I think

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that answer.

Comment: Why have you applied onClick on ListGroup also? You want to toggle only individual elements right?

Comment: for no particular reason. I was just trying things out.

Comment: I hope you got the problem in your code. It is about applying the same boolean state to all the listitems.

Comment: Yes, I am actually giving it a try now.